# How to remove bricks cemented on patio floor? Who do we hire?

Tags: floor, brick, patio, cement, service

My patio has some bricks cemented on top of older ones that I wish to remove. What kind of service do we need to hire for having the top bricks removed? Cement or mortar was used to set the bricks.

Comment: You're asking two questions--how to remove and who to hire. Which is it?

Comment: And what kind of outcome are you expecting? Should the original surface be restored to usability or acceptable appearance? Please revise to add that as well.

Comment: Stacy, please take the [tour]. We're not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve the bottom layer of brick the surface brick should be removed as delicately as possible. This may be difficult depending on how the top bricks were set in place. I would say ,based on your description, they are set in a mortar base. If so then the best technique for removal is to chisel them up. Insert a wide brick chisel (or similar tool that can be hammered) between the two brick faces. The surface brick will eventually break away (usually not in one piece).

You'll probably want to re-surface the patio again; the old mortar will still be adhered to the bottom brick. It may be best and cost efficient to start anew. You would save alot of time to have both levels of brick removed. Than, depending on your desire, a concrete patio can be poured. Or a sub-base of sand can be tamped for a brick patio. You needn't worry about cleaning the old brick just use the other side that's clean!

Any brute can demolish a patio with the right tools. If you are adamant to keep the bottom bricks intact you'd be wise to hire a mason or building contractor, but I believe they would say the same thing in that it's not worth the effort to keep the brick and to start anew.

Comment: Day laborers, +1. Except we're in the middle of a pandemic.... So this is DiY, by yourself, or you pick up the phone.

Answer (score 2):

Removing bricks set in cement/mortar is basically just a brute-force operation.

You can use any of the following methods:

1. A short 4 pound sledge hammer and mason chisel to break things apart at the joints
2. A full size 6-12 pound sledge hammer to just crush everything to dust and a pickaxe for chipping loose parts
3. An SDS hammer with a chisel attachment to quickly break through the joints
4. A full sized jack hammer would laugh at the endeavor

If you wish to minimize damage to the old brick underneath then choose option #1 or #3.

There will be leftover cement/mortar on the old bricks so you could grind that away with a diamond cup disc or chisel it away as much as possible.

You could feasibly hire just about any general contractor and they will be able to remove the new brick.

A mason would be preferable because they would know how to make the end result look nice.